# 405 POST Method Not Allowed using asp for Crystal report file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-7, asp-classic, crystal-reports

We are moving a project from IIS6, Windows Server 2003 to Windows 7, IIS7, VS2012 now.  Part of this project uses old asp files to open crystal report files.  It was working fine on our old server.  After I moved them to the new server.  It throws me an error message: "HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed."

We have a Report.asp file.  It uses a form post method to display a crystal report file.  Here is the code:

(form method="POST" action="/Reports/InfoNetOverDueDate1.rpt" target="_blank" id=frmOpenReport name=frmOpenReport>

I checked the Headers info.  It only Allows GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE.

Here is what I tried.  In IIS, under my Handler Mappings --> Add a Module Mapping.  Request Path: .rpt; Module: ProtocolSupportModule; Verbs: GET, POST.

It doesn't throw me any error message, but it doesn't show anything either.

Anybody there can help me with this?  Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hi Hling - see [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cc864bc8-1225-489c-b901-8016d656a5db/how-to-access-a-ssrs-report-from-a-classic-asp-page?forum=sqlreportingservices); might help.

Comment: Did you check how the handler mapping was set-up on the old server?